# iOS: Interactive UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I know this is a really "macro" question, but I don't know how to start.

I have an image (.png) that contains a lot of rectangles (it's an event map). The user can zoom  in/out the image.
I want to add some interaction for the map. When the user touch on an rectangle I want to identify which rectangle it is and show an label with the name.

I know how to get the X,Y, but the problem it's to calculate the rectangle's area and when the user zoom the image, I lost the original X/Y.

Sorry for the bad question, hope someone can help me.

My map it's loaded by this way:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"event-map.png"];
CGSize imageSize = image.size;
self.mapImage.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
self.mapImage.image = image;
self.scrollView.contentSize = imageSize;
self.scrollView.zoomScale = 0.29;
```

Comment: Hi Lucks, you are right about the "Macro" :-) So you could work out which pixel of the table picture that has been clicked on, but then what? As far as you have revealed, you don't have any way to turn this in to the identity of a table? I think you are going to need to access to this information. Instead of an image, could you describe the tables in a `plist` file, and then, for example, set up a `UIView` for each table. Then when these are tapped you could detect this.

Comment: Hi @Benjohn thanks for your answer. Do you have any tutorial or a link reference to develop this?

Answer (score 0):

On your rectangle view, you can use:

```
[self.window convertPoint:myPoint toView:self]
```

This will convert your point into your view space. Once there, you can calculate whether you hit a rectangle based on the rectangle's bounds within your view vs the converted point.

If you do not know the bounds of the rectangles within your image, but they are all of a very specific pixel colour, you could use fetch the data of your image and compare the hit pixel's colour with your expected colour.

Comment: I have an image that contains a lot of rectangles. How can I use your code?